# Using a CASE statement in ORDER BY clause with different data types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to use a `CASE` statement in my `ORDER BY` clause as follows:

```
DECLARE @SortOr TINYINT
SELECT  @SortOr = 1

SELECT  *
FROM    [Table]
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortOr = 1 THEN col1
              ELSE col2
         END
```

But it throws an error:

> Cannot convert varchar into tinyint.

What is the logic behind that? How can fix it?

Comment: A single `CASE` *expression* has to produce values of *one* data type. So if you have `THEN`s that produce values of different data types, the system uses the [precedence rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) to decide which ones to convert.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever do you mind if I add your comment to my answer as it's a great point and the real underlying issue that my solution solves? Will provide credit of course.

Comment: You will need to cast as columns in the CASE as VARCHAR.

Comment: @Tanner - feel free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying issue that @Damien_The_Unbeliever states perfectly in the comments is:

> A single `CASE` expression has to produce values of one data type. So if you have `THEN`s that produce values of different data types, the system uses the [precedence rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) to decide which ones to convert.

You can replicate your `CASE` statement to work around this, where each `CASE` returns a single value/data type. This would be better than converting all values to `VARCHAR` as suggested in the other answer, which should also perform better (you will have to test):

So new `ORDER BY` clause will look like:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortOr = 1 THEN col1 
         END ,
         CASE WHEN @SortOr != 1 THEN col2
         END -- If you need DESC it goes after END
```

Comment: Can't argue with that, nice workaround! Didn't even know yet you just let `CASE` return nothing and it still works in a comma separated `ORDER BY`:)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste never actually done it in real code, but was pretty sure it would work so tested it and learnt something new.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all returned values by the `CASE` statement to `VARCHAR` and it will work.

SQL Server tries to convert all your returned values implicitly, because they are part of the **same expression** and SQL Server wants them really to be the same type; it tries to convert to `INT`, because `INT` has higher [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) than `VARCHAR`; so you should set the same type for this explicitly.

Comment: I've tried to do this `case when @SortOr = 1 then convert(varchar(20),Col1) else convert(numeric(28,10),Col2) end`. Same error returned "Arithmetic overflow error converting..."

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood me, you need `all return paths` of your `CASE` to return the `SAME type`, so convert both to  `VARCHAR`, not one to `VARCHAR` and the other to `NUMERIC`